# 4-Manifolds of which there exist no Kirby diagrams

Tags: geometry, differential-topology, low-dimensional-topology, kirby-diagram, 4-manifolds

In 4-Manifold theory one makes often the use of Kirby Diagrams to construct 4-manifolds (compact or non-compact) with specific gauge and topological properties (for example small betti numbers, spin structure, etc.).

This raises a couple of questiona:

1.Is any compact or non-compact 4-manifold obtainable as a (finite or infinite) handle diagram ?

2.What are the properties needed for a compact or non-compact 4-manifold to be represented as a handle diagram ?

3.What are examples of 4-manifolds with no handle diagram ?

The diagrams can be as complicated as you want (so 0-, 2-, 3-, 4-) handles can be present. I do not know if you can get rid of all the 3-handles in the non-compact case.

This question came forth from the discussion [explicit "exotic" charts](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29123/explicit-exotic-charts/53482#53482) . I am trying to get help of more people on that, then putting those things in comments (the question of explicit charts of an $\mathbb{E}\mathbb{R}^4$ is another one, albeit interesting in it's own right).

The question is answered by Bob Gompf by email, see my comment for the main part of his answer.

Comment: A related question on math overflow: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54143/whats-the-kirby-diagram-of-a-universal-mathbbr4

Comment: Usually one finds a handle decomposition via a Morse function, but these don't behave so well in the noncompact case, so something subtle is going on. A quick Google search turned up this reference http://books.google.com/books?id=WHjO9K6xEm4C&lpg=PA1049&ots=wbRQB-spWC&dq=existence%20of%20morse%20functions%20for%20noncompact%20manifolds&pg=PA1049#v=onepage&q=existence%20of%20morse%20functions%20for%20noncompact%20manifolds&f=false which states that there are Morse functions on every noncompact manifold with no critical points.!

Comment: I have received a mail from Bob Gompf on this, seems that indeed every 4-manifold has a Kirby diagram, so my question is answered by external source.

Comment: The problem is that one cannot draw such a thing easily (but is does exist). There is also the problem of attaching infinitely many handles to its 0-handle, which can be fixed either by adding a collar to the boundary along with each handle, or introduceing canceling handle pairs so that there are infinitely many 0-handles.

Comment: In particular, Bob doesm't know any handle diagrams of
large exotic R^4's. All known examples of these require infinitely many 3-handles in their handle decomposition

Answer (score 4):

Weird to answer your own question, but one becomes wiser with years. Seens that every 4-manifold can be represented as a Kirby Diagram. Problem is that these things can get very complicated (infinite many 1- or 3-handles, or infinite 0-handles, kinks in the handles, etc). So the question can be answered negatively: there are none.

Comment: All smooth 4 manifolds you mean.